# Create an array from a mysqli prepared statment

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a simple script that I am trying to understand why it will not work, and how to get exactly what I want.

What I want to get is an array, call it `$results` and have the data stored as follows

```
$results ->
    $row1 ->
        $field1
        $field2
        $field3
        $field4
        $field5
    $row2 ->
        $field1
        $field2
        $field3
        $field4
        $field5
```

etc...

but I cant even get the mysqli to loop out the results at all, here is my code...

```
require_once ('lib/constants.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to Database.');

$query = "SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT 0, 20";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->execute();
$row = array();
stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $row);

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [mysqli_result::fetch_assoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) method on PHP.net for better understanding.

Below is a quick example

```
require_once ('lib/constants.php');
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Error connecting to Database.');

$query = "SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT 0, 20";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['myfield'];
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check [mysqli_result:::fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead of mysqli_result::fetch_assoc

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM employees LIMIT 0, 20";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $array_assoc = $result->fetch_all();
    
    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}
```